# Django: Validator function

Tags: django

I have a Contract class in my model. A contract can be related with a person or with another contract which is an extended contract of a previous one. All good so far.

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person) #person hired
    contract = models.OneToOneField('self', blank = True, null = True) #allows to extend a contract
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, blank = True, null = True) #related project
```

So when I want to extend a contract I put the name of a person and the field contract shows me all the contracts in the data base. What a I need is that when I put a person the field contract only shows me the contracts of that person.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To access only one person's contract, you can:

either do the following in a view:

```
person = Person.objects.get(...)
contracts = person.contract_set.all()
```

or, do it in a template:

```
{% for contract in person.contract_set.all %}
    {{ contract }}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'm using the Admin interface, should I add it in the admin.py?

Comment: @Alex_Loar I think you should use [`TabularInline`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline) or [`StackedInline`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.StackedInline)